# What does this 「こなきゃ」 (bottom-right panel) mean here?

Tags: grammar

Is it a contraction of the 「～なければいけない」 form?

If so, why is it used with 「こ」 here, shouldn't it simply be 「剣を**取らなきゃ**！」?

[image]

Comment: なきゃ is just short for なければならない. It’s actually just short for なければ, but often people use it in place of なければならない as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

くる goes to こない, so 取ってくる goes to 取ってこない. Hopefully it should already be clear how こなければならない contracts to こなきゃ.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorten expression. 取ってこなければいけない！ → 取ってこなければ！ → 取ってこなきゃ！